# How to print random items from multiple concatenated lists based on user input choice in python?

Tags: python

I want to make a simple app that suggests an artist to listen based on user input genre choice. I have concatenated lists(genres) and it can print random item from any of the lists using random.choice. However i want it to print a random item only from the list that user inputs, not random item from random list.

Tried with changing between elif and else. Tried making a for loop, but without much success.

```
import random
a= ["x", "y"]
b= ["z", "k"]
print("please choose between a or b")
answer = input ()
if answer == "a":
    print("You should check out : " , random.choice(a+b))
elif answer == "b":
    print("You should check out : " , random.choice(b))
```

I expect an output to be a random item from the list `a` when the user inputs "a", and random item from the list `b` when the user inputs "b", but the output is a random item from either list `a` or `b` no matter if user input is strictly `a` or `b`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the root of your issue is the `a+b` bit under user input = 'a'. Also, you can put your prompt into your `input()` statement. It seems to work fine for me when I run:

```
import random

a = ["x", "y"]
b = ["z", "k"]
answer = input("please choose between a or b \n>>>")
if answer == "a":
    print("You should check out : ", random.choice(a))
elif answer == "b":
    print("You should check out : ", random.choice(b))
```

Sample outputs:

```
please choose between a or b 
>>>a
You should check out :  x
```

```
please choose between a or b 
>>>b
You should check out :  k
```

Took a few tries to get 'z' but it will show up:

```
please choose between a or b 
>>>b
You should check out :  z
```

The `"\n"` is a new line character and is how I got the prompt `>>>` to show on the next line in my output

Comment: I tried that as well but then it doesn't print items from the list b. Only from list a for me(x,y). It will not show z or x. Basically the same as the other answer, except that i don't understand the purpose of \n>>> in your code.

Comment: @user11334298 It definitely does show 'x' or 'z' if you run my code as posted. Check my sample output!

Comment: You are right. I will see if there is another issue with my code.

Comment: I added additional or that messed it up. I just put another option with or in my if statement. It works

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is you are doing `random.choice(a+b)` instead of `random.choice(a)`. Below works fine for me

```
import random
a= ["x", "y"]
b= ["z", "k"]
print("please choose between a or b")
answer = input ()
if answer == "a":
    print("You should check out : " , random.choice(a))
elif answer == "b":
    print("You should check out : " , random.choice(b))
```

Comment: I tried that as well but then it doesn't print items from the list b. Only from list a for me(x,y). It will not show z or x.